Change in water level in communicating cylindrical and pyramidal tanks
This is a problem given to us in a PLC programming class. There are two connected tanks, a square pyramid with base side length $A$ and a cone with base radius $R$, both of height $H$. The tanks are being filled and emptied simultaneously by two pipes. Every second, a certain (not constant!) volume of water is added and subtracted through each ($Vin$ and $Vout$, with $ΔV$ as the difference.) We also know the current water level $h$. I need to determine the amount by which the water level will rise or fall ($Δh$). (We are told to ignore the vessel connecting the two tanks).
I think I've figured it out, but I would love for someone to proofread me...
$a$ is the current pyramid side length, $r$ is current cone radius:
$a =A(1-h/H); r= R(1-h/H)$
$S = Spyr+ Scone= a^2+π*r^2 =(A^2+R^2)*(1-h/H)^2$
$ΔV=\int_h^{h+Δh} S(h)dh = \int_h^{h+Δh}(A^2+R^2)*(1-\frac{2h}{H}+\frac{h^2}{H^2})dh$
$\frac{ΔV}{A^2+R^2} = \int_h^{h+Δh}(1-\frac{2h}{H}+\frac{h^2}{H^2})dh= (h-\frac{h^2}{H}+\frac{h^3}{3H^2})|_h^{h+Δh}$
$(h-\frac{h^2}{H}+\frac{h^3}{3H^2})|_h^{h+Δh} = -Δh+\frac{2hΔh+Δh^2}{H}+\frac{-3h^2Δh-3hΔh^2-Δh^3}{3H^2}=$
$=(1+\frac{2h}{H}-\frac{h^2}{H^2})Δh+(\frac{1}{H}-\frac{h}{H^2})Δh^2-\frac{Δh^3}{3H^2}$
Overall, we get: $(1+\frac{2h}{H}-\frac{h^2}{H^2})Δh+(\frac{1}{H}-\frac{h}{H^2})Δh^2-\frac{Δh^3}{3H^2}-\frac{ΔV}{A^2+R^2}=0,$ which we will then need to solve for Δh.
It feels a bit too complicated. I really want to avoid solving a cubic equation, since dealing with potentially complex roots on this system will be a nightmare. Which is why I'm wondering if this is even correct, or maybe there's some easier way I'm blatantly missing? Thanks!

You are expected to do a linear approximation to the volume changes. In each case, $\Delta V \approx A(h)\Delta h$, where $A(h)$ is the cross-sectional area at height $h$. I find it hard to follow the problem set-up, but I assume the $\Delta V$ matches in the two shapes.

@TedShifrin you think that would be alright? Won't these errors add up over time?

In the limit (say this happens in a time interval $\Delta t$ and we take $\Delta t\to 0$), you get a differential equation to solve, and that gives you a precise answer. I don't quite understand how this arises in a programming class, but in a second-semester calculus class, that would be what happens next.

If $\Delta V$ is small, you can try to expand $\Delta h$ in powers of $\Delta V$: $$\Delta h=k_1\Delta V +k_2\Delta V^2+k_3\Delta V^3.$$ Subtitute into your equation and equate to zero the coefficients of the firts three powers of $\Delta V$ to find $k_1$, $k_2$ and $k_3$.

@Intelligentipauca That sounds interesting; How do I get it to that form though (from $ΔV=k1Δh+k2Δh^2+k3Δh^3$)?

@IraI.I. Substitute the expression above for $\Delta h$ into your equation. Equating to zero the resulting coefficient of $\Delta V$ you can find $k_1$, equating then to zero the coefficient of $\Delta V^2$ you can find $k_2$, and so on for $k_3$. Of course you must check a posteriori that those terms are increasingly small.

@IraI.I. And of course the result is an approximation, it's to you to decide if that's good enough for you. Otherwise, you can use some numerical method to solve the cubic equation.

Two changes can simplify the calculations: First, stop thinking of the tanks as separate. Together they form a generalized cone with some total volume $B$. Second, measure "height" from the apex, not the base, and scale it as a ratio to $H$: $y = \frac{H - h}H = 1 - \frac hH$. Then when the water is at $y$, the unfilled portion of the tank has volume $By^3$ (since the tops of generalized cones are similar to the entire cone). Then the equation becomes $$(\Delta y - y)^3 = \frac{\Delta V}B - y^3$$

@PaulSinclair way late to seeing this, sorry... just out of curiosity, is there any way to convert these two "cones" into one if they have different heights (full heights, base to apex)? It doesn't seem like it should work, but I could be wrong...
